# Upper and lower bounds for VC dimension of union and intersection of hypothesis sets

Tags: machine-learning, vc-dimension

Suppose we have K hypothesis sets - $H_1, H_2,...,H_K$, each with VC dimension $d_{VC}(H_i)$. What will be the upper and lower bounds on the VC dimensions of the union and intersection of these hypothesis sets?

I am able to do partial calculations. For the intersection, the VC dimension has to be the minimum $d_{VC}(H_i)$ but unable to give a lower bound - is it zero?

For the union, the VC dimension has a lower bound of sum of the all the VC dimensions - we can divide the input into sets of sizes equal to each one's VC dimensions. However, here again I am stuck with the calculations of upper bound. Can anyone give me any suggestions or leads?